# MVC ActionLink Odd Routing Behavior -- Adds link to the end of the url after hash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

**I'm working on an MVC .Net 4.5 web app and my links are misbehaving.**

Here's my starting URL:  `http://localhost:58982/Game/Index`

**Here's the RAZR code and resulting html:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Occasion", "Index", "Occasion")
<a href="/Occasion">Occasion</a>
```

But when I click the link my URL looks like this:  `http://localhost:58982/Game/Index#/Occasion`

When a link takes me to the same page the browser does not refresh and the controller is not called.

Is there a setting I need to change somewhere?

Comment: Have you implemented any custom routing rules? If so, include them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your action takes no parameter you don't need to pass parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Occasion", "Index", "Occasion")
```

but if your action takes parameter:

```
public ActionResult Index(int ID)
{
//
}
```

it would be something like this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Occasion", "Index", "Occasion", new {Id=Model.Id},null)
```